# Change website to .php from .html , will this hurt my seo rankings

Tags: php, html, seo

Quick question.

I have a client with an HTML based website which ranks very, very high for SEO and has been around for 8 years.

I want to revamp his site using php templates and implement some CMS.

Will my re-writing the pages from .html to .php hurt his ranking in any way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If it breaks incoming links, it will definitely break your SEO unless you do the correct redirections for each ('moved permanently') rather than 404. However you don't have to change any of your extensions at all - just configure your web server to process .html files as PHP. What sort of server are you running? Shared Linux host/cPanel?

Comment: Cool, maybe try [this](http://www.lgr.ca/blog/2007/02/process-html-as-php.html) or [this](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/cpanel/apache-handlers-running-html-as-php).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to do a `301 redirect` from the .html to .php if possible. Alternatively, you can setup a `mod_rewrite` rule for the `.html` files to be rewritten as `.php.` That'd probably be the easier route, and how I would do it.

Comment: +1, just barely beat me to it :)

Comment: if I do a mod_rewrite, I can use PHP code in those pages?

Comment: @eberswine Absolutely. To the server, those are PHP files. To everyone else who goes off a file extension, it'll be an HTML file.

Answer (score 3):

You could also configure Apache to parse PHP within HTML files:

`AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .htm`

Answer (score 2):

Just use this Mod Rewrite and your problem will be solved :) It will rewrite .PHP as .HTML

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html $1\.php
```

Good luck!

Comment: This would do the same as a 301 redirect, right? Maybe a better answer! The other way, I would have to 301 redirect every page. But with YOUR method, it would be ALL pages, right ?